# Cleaner way to specify type to get from a std::variant?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

I've got code that can be simplified to

```
std::variant<float, int> v[2] = foo();
int a = std::get<decltype(a)>(v[0]);
float b = std::get<decltype(b)>(v[1]);
```

Obviously this can go throw if `foo()` returns the wrong variants, but that's not my problem here. (The real code has a `catch`). My problem is that the `decltype(a)` violates the Don't Repeat Yourself principle.

Is there a cleaner way to initialize a and b, and still throw if the types do not match expectations? In particular, I **don't** want a `static_cast<int>(std::get<float>(v))` if the variant contains a float while I'm trying to initialize an `int`.

Comment: Is this feasible: `auto a = std::get<int>(v[0]);` ?

Comment: "`decltype(a)` violates the Don't Repeat Yourself principle." How so? You aren't repeating the type of `a`

Comment: You can use auto as @paolo suggested or index the types with numbers, i.e. `int a = std::get<1>(v[0])`

Comment: @DominikRafacz: Magic numbers feel worse than DRY violations to me. *shrugs*.

Comment: @Caleth: But you are repeating `a` itself. It's not a major violation (changing the declared type of `a` only requires changing one piece still), but it does mean you need to repeat the name of `a` (which in real, vaguely self-documenting code is likely much longer) twice even though it's logically only relevant the once, which is a pain.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yeah, I completely agree. I only suggested that as I am also not sure what OP meant by DRY violation.

Comment: @paolo: Good comment, but in the real code the objects being initialized are class members.

Comment: Ah, **now** you tell us :)

Comment: There's a parallel between this and the idiomatic C `int *a = malloc(sizeof *a);`, where the latter doesn't seem at all unreadable or unDRY to me. Maybe it's the extra token soup in C++ that makes this so unpalatable. Because I find myself deterred as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could wrap your call to `get` in a template that implicitly converts to the target type.

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct variant_unwrapper {
    std::variant<Ts...> & var;
    template <typename T>
    operator T() { return std::get<T>(var); }
};

template<typename... Ts>
variant_unwrapper(std::variant<Ts...> &) -> variant_unwrapper<Ts...>;
```

If you are targeting C++20, you don't need the deduction guide

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/167d5c29a650b613)

Comment: But: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db6fb26632afd38e (if that's a problem)

Comment: @PaulSanders - You didn't actually initialize `v[2]` with a `short`. There isn't an actual problem in that snippet.

Comment: @PaulSanders https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f54c84077ae8fa73

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Good point

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried your coliru code on compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/cPYhz9n6z, it compiles with GCC 13.1, but doesn't compile with Clang 16.0.0 (released March 18 2023, nearly a year after your answer). Do you think this is due to unfinished clang feature support, or a difference of opinion in compilers?

Comment: @Paradox for some reason clang needs a deduction guide for `variant_unwrapper`, [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/f9r6GsKea)

Answer (score 10):

IMO it would be nice to allow template deduction to take over, so providing a helper function should do the job:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename...VariantParams>
void get_from(const std::variant<VariantParams...>& v, T& value)
{
    value = ::std::get<T>(v);
}

int a;

get_from(v[0], a);
```

Answer (score 5):

As [@paulo says in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72955067/cleaner-way-to-specify-type-to-get-from-a-stdvariant#comment128856641_72955067), seems like the DRY solution is to use `auto` for the declaration, changing:

```
int a = std::get<decltype(a)>(v[0]);
```

to:

```
auto a = std::get<int>(v[0]);
```

You only name the type (`int`) and the variable (`a`) once each. Doesn't work if you separate declaration and initialization, so you'd still need:

```
int a;
...
a = std::get<decltype(a)>(v[0]);
```

in that case, but if you write all your C++ code deferring declarations until the point of definition, it's not needed often.